# Google plus photo editor (downloading editing tools problem)

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, cache, google-plus-photos

I am using a [Micromax Canvas a74](http://www.gsmarena.com/micromax_a74_canvas_fun-5759.php) which runs on Jelly Bean. I have Google Plus installed on my phone, which has another app named **Photos** that helps to sync our photos to Gogle's cloud storage.

My problem is when I clean my cache using Clean Master it clears the local cache on my phone, which makes download the online editing tools for the 'Photos app editor'. In other words, when I try to edit my photos using the Google+ editor, it will download some editing tools to my phone's cache, and when I clear my cache I have to wait for the app to download the tools again before I can edit a photo.

Is a way (or an app) to erase the cache using an **ignore list**, which can ignore system default apps?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

I recommend using [UClean](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ucweb.master) instead of another cache cleaning app. It has an ignore list for system apps, so I could add the Google+ Photos app to the ignore list and prevent the cache from getting cleared.

It also has a folder ignore list, where we can specify the folders to be omitted at the time of cache listing. So UClean fixed my problem.